# How can i stop a mouseevent in javascript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

```
function pauseScene(evt:MouseEvent):void
{   
stop();
pause_btn.visible = false;
play_btn.visible = true;
}
```

I have written the above code in Actionscript to stop a mouse event. Now I want to convert that into Javascript so that the scene in flash cc will be converted to Html5. For that I have used the below code as

```
function pausescene()
{
 this.stop();
 }
```

But this is not satisfying my requirement. Please do help me.

Comment: You want to stop any default action or stop it's propagation ?

Comment: I want to stop an animation(action).

Comment: What does `stop` do ? It will stop the animation ? Why you used `this.stop()` ? Because `this` is function context. Can you post how `stop` has been implemented ? Are you seeing any errors in console ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`event.preventDefault()` prevents the default behaviour, but will not stop its propagation to further event listeners.

`event.stopPropagation()` will not prevent the default behaviour, but it will stop its propagation.

You can use a combination of both.

Example code:

```
myElement.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    // do your logics here
});
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Answer (score 1):

If you can capture the event object, you can use the preventDefault() to stop it

```
function catchMouseEvent(e){
     e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Does JS support typing (ex. event:MouseEvent)??